# Can you conditionally "SendClaims" based on the Protocol?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am wondering if there is a way to have a single `SignUpOrSignin` policy that will conditionally `SendClaims` with either the `JwtIssuer` or a custom `SamlIssuer`

I was assuming that I would need to use some sort of "Claims Resolver" to set a Claim with the protocol information, and then use a Precondition to conditionally decide how to return the claims.

I didn't see anything in https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples that led me to believe one way or another. I was also not finding anything obvious about the `<Protocol />` elements used throughout.

Appreciate any guidance!

Comment: You can emit a claim from technical profiles for protocol used. Based  on the claim you can use skip an orchestration step.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal - I assume you mean adding an `OutputClaim` to a technical profile, which I can easily do. What I can't figure out is how to determine the protocol being used. I don't want the protocol that the Technical Profile used to exchange claims, but what protocol the request is using.

Comment: Why not use two relying party files and two user journeys? That’ll generate two policy ids that you can then use to determine what protocol to be used. How is this different from a query param to control it?